# How to create data base link in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

How to create data base link in oracle 11 g to Access Tables.
[image: Regarding database link creation]

Comment: What does `'local'` refer to? Do you have a `tnsnames.ora` entry with that name?

Comment: 'local' represents  my servicename.

Comment: I am getting data by using query as select count(*) from employee@local.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have copied the [example in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5005.htm#i2061718) without really understanding it.

The `USING 'local'` part of the statement is creating a link to 'the `local` database', where `local` is the service name of a database. (The example is a bit confusing, to be fair).

When the link is used it tries to interpret `local` as a service name, appending the current database's domain, as [the docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF53886):

> ### USING '*connect string*'
>
> Specify the service name of a remote database. If you specify only the
>   database name, then Oracle Database implicitly appends the database
>   domain to the connect string to create a complete service name.
>   Therefore, if the database domain of the remote database is different
>   from that of the current database, then you must specify the complete
>   service name.

If you're trying to create a link back into the same database - which would be a bit odd but I've seen it done in place of grant access across schemas, and that seems to be what the example is hinting at - then you can replace `'local'` in the `USING` clause with the service name of your current database (e.g. `USING 'orcl'`, or whatever).

You can also use a TNS alias; if your `tnsnames.ora` has an entry for `SOME_DB` which points to the SID or service name of another database, you can have `USING`'some_db'`. You should be able to use any [connect string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements009.htm#sthref786) I think; certainly Easy Connect is allowed. There's more in the [net services admin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/concepts.htm#CIAHJEDI).

Comment: instead of using those userid,password i will use my database userid, password and service name